# Unable to receive sign request on Subsocial

Tags: polkadot-js, subsocial

I'm trying to post on Subsocial but when I hit `"Create Post"` the sign request isn't popping up. I have tried logging in and out, changing the sign request type, disabling and enabling the `extension`, updating `metadata`, and I have been all through the extension trying to get the signature request to pop up. I do have a ping next to the extension logo saying "1" with a red square, signifying that I have a sign request but for some reason I can't access it. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

When you first visit the site you'll be asked to 'Auth' the site, was this done?  If not please verify that the site is allowed in Manage Website Access.

Comment: yep! If i go under "Manage Website Access" app.subsocial.network is enabled

Comment: Hey @paradox-paranodes-io , good to see you here! I think your answer is more of a clarifying Q/statement that should be in the comments to the post, not the answer directly 

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Subsocial is prompting for the signature, but you're having trouble seeing the pop-up.

When the Polkadot extension notifies you that there's a pending extrinsic to sign but you don't see the window that's usually because of either of these two reasons:

1. Your browser is blocking the pop-up window of the extension
2. You're using more than one screen and the pop-up is on a different screen.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Probably a dumb question, but have you disabled all ad-blockers for the site? That might be interfering with some js... (also you didn't mention which browser / OS you were having trouble with)